# i need to change connection type to keep-alive in laravel 10 on an audio file

Tags: laravel, audio, http-headers, response

I have a local laravel project where music is uploaded, i then validate and store it in storage/music folder i created. I can display the song but i can not change where im listening (i.e. i want to skip to 2:00 minute mark) I figured i need to set the response headers of the music file to connection:keep-alive. But i am not sure where and how to do it, would like some help!
below is my storemethod in my TrackController which i created with resource routes.

laravel version:
Laravel Framework 10.25.2

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $formFields = $request->validate([
            'artist' => ['required'],
            'title' => ['required'],
            'track' => ['audio'],
        ]);
        $trackFile = $request->file('track');
        $trackFileName = $trackFile->getClientOriginalName();
        if(Storage::disk('public')->exists('music/' . $trackFileName)){
            return back()->withErrors(['track' => 'Track Already exists']);
        }
        $formFields['track_name'] = $trackFile->storeAs('music', $trackFileName, 'public');
        $formFields['user_id'] = Auth::id();
        Track::create($formFields);
        return back()->with('success', 'Track ' . $formFields['artist'] . '-' . $formFields['title'] . ' was added!');
    }
```

ive tried changing the headers of the view and the file but nothing has worked so far i am also not sure where to change this in the controller (store or show method?)